# Error in if condition on mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, conditional-statements

I have written a small trigger function in MySQL . This is the trigger query i have written and the condition are not checked direct default value of created_id is assigned.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `complain_attend_log` AFTER INSERT ON `attend_complain`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE attend_created INT;
    DECLARE created_id INT default 5;

SET attend_created = (SELECT attend_created FROM allotments WHERE complain_id = NEW.complain_id);

IF(attend_created = 1) THEN
    SET created_id = 6;
END IF;

INSERT INTO complain_logs
VALUES(null,NEW.complain_id,NEW.allotment_id,NEW.attend_complain_id,NEW.is_closed,created_id,1,now(),1,now());
END
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: without checking if condition directly insert value 5 as declare default value .

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem but I would avoid using the same name for variables as are used for columns and I would look closely at what is returned from the select in the first set attend_created statement (possibly writing to a debug_table)

Comment: Do not use the same name for variables and columns. In `(SELECT attend_created FROM allotments ... ` MySQL will use the value of the *variable* (which is `null`, so it keeps being `null` no matter what you find in the table).

Comment: it's working .. thank you @Solarflare